# How to check if a Sudoku is possible in Python

Tags: python, sudoku

I am making a Sudoku solver in python, and wish for it to check if the Sudoku the user inputted is possible. I already have the functions `is_valid`, `find_next_full`, and `find_next_empty`. I need this to be as concise as possible, as most other answers are around 100 lines long. My previous attempt has frozen when I gave it a puzzle with more than two numbers in. The code that makes this happen is this:

```
def find_next_empty(puzzle):
        """
        This function finds the next empty space on the board
        """
        for row in range(9):
            for column in range(9):
                if puzzle[row][column] == -1:
                    return row, column
        return None, None
def find_next_full(puzzle):
        """
        This function finds the next space that is not empty
        """
        for row in range(9):
            for column in range(9):
                if puzzle[row][column] != -1:
                    return row, column
        return None, None
def is_valid(puzzle, guess, row, col):
        """
        This function checks if a guess can go in the specified place
        """
        row_vals = puzzle[row]
        if guess in row_vals:
            return False
        col_vals = [puzzle[i][col] for i in range(9)]
        if guess in col_vals:
            return False
        row_start = (row // 3) * 3
        col_start = (col // 3) * 3
        for r in range(row_start, row_start + 3):
            for c in range(col_start, col_start + 3):
                if puzzle[r][c] == guess:
                    return False
        return True
def is_possible(puzzle):
        row, col = find_next_empty(puzzle)
        if row == None:
            print("This sudoku is already solved.")
            return False
        row, col = find_next_full(puzzle)
        print(type(row))
        while row != None:
            now = puzzle[row][col]
            puzzle[row][col] = -1
            if is_valid(puzzle, now, row, col):
                print("Square ", row, col, " is possible")
            else:
                print("This is an impossible sudoku.")
                return False
            previousrow, previouscol = row,col
            row, col = find_next_full(puzzle)
            puzzle[previousrow][previouscol] = now
print(is_possible([[9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]))
```

I am using `-1` as a blank space.

EDIT: I have tried just trying to solve it, but it ends up in a loop that takes quite a while. I need it to solve quickly. The code that I use to solve the Sudoku is as follows:

```
def solve_sudoku(puzzle):
    global count
    row, col = find_next_empty(puzzle)
    if row is None and col is None:
        print("Solved")
        return True
    for guess in range(1,10):
        count += 1
        if is_valid(puzzle, guess, row, col):
            puzzle[row][col] = guess
            print("Square ", row, col, " is valid with ", guess)
            if solve_sudoku(puzzle):
                return True, puzzle
        puzzle[row][col] = -1
    return False
```

Comment: What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: I need a way to easily and quickly check if a Sudoku is impossible, without masses of code.

Comment: It only checks if a guess is in the correct place. It's the `is_possible` function that I need help with.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a faster way to determine if a puzzle *is* solvable, without actually solving it? (Finding a solution would be a *constructive* proof that a solution exists; some problems admit non-constructive proofs. I don't know the status of Sudoku myself, but I suspect finding a solution is optimal in some sense.)

Comment: @Pazzel, the error in your code is not so difficult, but there is a misunderstanding to get out of the way: if the numbers already present on the puzzle are not directly violating the rules you still cannot be sure that the puzzle can be solved. So your intended approach will not work.

Comment: What are the other ways, and is it possible to check for them? If so, please could someone guide me through rewriting my `is_possible` function to check for them?

Comment: How do you know it "locks"? You give your program a Sudoku with 79 empty squares, which allows for 9^79 possibilities. Even if it does not try them all out, it might fill a fraction of the Sudoku so that it is not solvable any more and then spent years trying out all possibilities for the remaining squares.

Comment: In [this video](https://youtu.be/G_UYXzGuqvM) is explained the shortest function to solve a Sudoku I know.

Comment: If you want to learn about advanced methods to solve a Sudoku, read about [Bron Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm). I leave you a very accessible [Python notebook](https://github.com/je-suis-tm/graph-theory/blob/master/sudoku.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

One general hint I give people, trying to do programs around Sudokus, is to represent the puzzle in a one-dimensional list (instead of two-dimensional) and define rows, columns and 3x3 squares as list of indexes in range 0-80.

Example:

```
subsets = [[9*j+i for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)] \
          + [[9*i+j for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)] \
          + [[i%3 + 9*(i//3) + j for i in range(9)] for j in [0,3,6,27,30,33,54,57,60]]

# Define a dictionary, mapping each pos (in range(81)) to its three subsets
subsets_for_pos = {pos: [s for s in subsets if pos in s] for pos in range(81)}
```

With this, you can just access any set of row, column and 3x3-square indexes as `subsets_for_pos[pos]` (where pos is 0-80). Example for the middle square:

```
>>> subsets_for_pos[40]
[[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [4, 13, 22, 31, 40, 49, 58, 67, 76], [30, 31, 32, 39, 40, 41, 48, 49, 50]]
```

Given that, some of your functions above will become a lot shorter and thus easier to maintain. `find_next_empty(puzzle)` can be simply written as `next(i for i in range(81) if puzzle[i] == -1)` and is_valid also becomes a lot more readable:

```
def is_valid(puzzle, guess, pos):
    ''' Check that guess at pos does not violate the puzzle '''
    for subs in subsets_for_pos[pos]:
        if any(puzzle[i] == guess for i in subs):
            return False
    return True
```

or (even shorter but less readable):

```
def is_valid(puzzle, guess, pos):
    ''' Check that guess at pos does not violate the puzzle '''
    return not any(any(puzzle[i] == guess for i in subs) for subs in subsets_for_pos[pos])
```

Having given all those generic tips, the facts remain that there is no shortcut on saying whether a Sudoku is solvable without solving it, and solving a puzzle with only two squares filled using normal backtracking might not have reasonable run-time.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to suggest the idea that a Sudoku with two squares filled is hard. Actually is easier than it seems as most of the squares can be filled without restrictions.

Comment: You are correct. My (wrong) assumption was that if one was to "blindly" fill the first three rows of a puzzle, one would create an unsolvable Sudoku and backtracking would take forever to find out it is unsolvable. But it seems that there are many solutions no matter how one solves the first rows.